# gdb does not find any symbols when analysing a coredump since a migration to cmake compilation chain

Tags: cmake, gdb, symbols, coredump

I have a project that compiled an executable with codeblocks. I have modified the compilation chain to use CMAKE. The compilation and execution works well.
The problem is that when a coredump is generated after a crash. I analyse it with gdb with the command: `gdb myapp --core=core.1222`

If I runs gdb on the computer where executable has been generated, I get all symbols and I can explore threads and local variables.

The problem is when I try to run gdb on another computer,  it does not manage to get any symbol. I got the following warning:
`BFD: Warning: /home/.../core.1222 is truncated: expected core file size >= 307032064, found: 307027968`
"info threads" in gdb display ?? instead function name.

My CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ../bin )
SET(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS ON)
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_STRIP FALSE)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS            "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")
```

I had compare the invoked make command used by codeblocks and cmake. There are quite similarly except the option -o:
with cmake

```
-o CMakeFiles/monappilcation.dir/home/.../main.cpp.o
```

and with codeblock:

```
-o obj/Release/.../main.cpp.o
```

The command `nm -a` display all the symbols correctly.

My questions are:

- How does gdb compute the expected size?
- How can I retrieve the symbol by using cmake compilation tool chain?

Any of your suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Everything works on computer A. It's not clear from your message whether your problem happens when you get the core dump on coputer B and try to analyse it on B, or whether you try to analyse the core produced on B using GDB on A.

Comment: Binary is generated on computer A. It's executed on computer B where it produces the core. When I analyse the core on computer A, everything works fine. but when I try to analyse on another computer, it does not works, gdb does not find symbol and warns about expected size.

Comment: You are still not clear: what is *another computer*? Is it computer `C` (i.e. *not* `A` and not `B`)?

Comment: Sorry about this unclearness, 'another computer' is all computers except computer A. Thanks to take time for my issue, I'm quite blocked with it. I've done many search on the net without any response.

Comment: If you aren't using [reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/), there could probably be tons of reasons what you're trying to do isn't working.